# Whats the difference between calling function loadText vs loadText() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple JS function that loads text lines to an unordered-list.

Javascript

```
function loadText() {
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Text1";
    document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "Text2";
    document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = "Text3";
}
window.onload = loadText;
```

HTML

```
<ul id="textlist">
        <li id="text1"></li>
        <li id="text2"></li>
        <li id="text3"></li>
</ul>
```

This actually works in the browser(Chrome), but when I use `window.onload = loadText();` instead of `window.onload = loadText;`. I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I assumed it was because the DOM was not read so I tried ondomready but get the same problem there. However changing `window.onload = loadText();` back to `window.onload = loadText;` works again.

Feels a bit weird to me that this would cause a difference. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.onload = loadText;` tells the browser to execute `loadText` when the document was loaded. That means that `document.getElementById` will be available (and work correctly) in `loadText`.

`window.onload = loadText();` executes `loadText` immediately and assigns the return value (`undefined`) to `window.onload`. The assignment is therefore useless and the function won't work.

You want `window.onload = loadText` here, I have no idea why you even tried `window.onload = loadText();`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..it was a typo, but I just wanted to clarify how it works...so in essence the (undefined) return value was screwing it up...

Comment: @mobbarley No, the immediate invocation of the function screwed it. You simply called the function before `onload`.

Answer (score 5):

```
window.onload = loadText();
```

this immediately executes loadText and stores its return value in window.onlad

```
window.onload = loadText;
```

this makes window.onload reference the loadText function. Calling window.onload() will now be the same as calling loadText()

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload = loadText();` will execute immediately when browser will read the line 
`window.onload = loadText;`  will assign the value loadText and let the browser load complete dom